# Ubuntu:Permission denied error

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04, dicom, permission-denied

I have downloaded mricron dicom to nifti converter file and i would like to run it through terminal , I am incurring following error

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/media/dev/Daten/mricron_lx$ ./mricron
bash: ./mricron: Permission denied
```

I have tried chmod -R 777 but still it doesnot work

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ chmod -R 777 '/media/dev/Daten/mricron_lx' 
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ cd '/media/dev/Daten/mricron_lx' 
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/media/dev/Daten/mricron_lx$ ./mricron
bash: ./mricron: Permission denied
```

Kindly let me know what is the problem in my trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set execution permissions on the containing folder but on the file itself:

```
chmod +x ./mricron
```

Afterwards you can execute the file. But honestly, this is more of a question for the Unix Stack Exchange and nothing that hasn't already been answered somewhere.